# change icon with condition inside Macro - Twig

Tags: symfony, macros, conditional-statements

I have set up a macro for an icon in a sorting table (using Knppaginator)

What I would like is to know how to actually change the icon arrow on click when sorting the table.

I will show you my code, right know only one icon has been set up

**my macro** file where is the icon arrow (i'm using font-awesome)

```
{% macro icon_class(type) %}
    {% set type_class = {
        sort: 'fa-angle-down'
    } %}
    {{ type_class[type] }}
{% endmacro %}
```

**My controller**

```
private function resultsAction(Request $request, User $user, $type, $archive)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

        $qb = $em->getRepository("STUserBundle:Operation")->getQueryByTypeAndPro($type, $user, $archive);

        $results = $paginator->paginate(
            $qb,
            $request->query->get('page',1),
            $request->query->get('limit',50),
            [
                'defaultSortFieldName'      => 'opn.dateCreation',
                'defaultSortDirection' => 'desc'
            ]
        );

        return array("results" => $results, "archive" => $archive);
    }

public function offreAction(Request $request, User $user, $archive = false)
    {
        return $this->resultsAction($request, $user, Operation::OFFRE_COMMERCIALE, $archive);
    }
```

**my template**

```
{% import "STBackofficeBundle:Macros:icons.html.twig" as icons %}

<th><i class="fa {{ icons.icon_class('sort') }}" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>
```

How can I do that with a condition like `if` `elseif` ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer for it.
i dit that

```
{% macro icon_class(type, direction) %}
    {% set type_class = {
        sort: direction == 'desc' ? 'fa-angle-down' : 'fa-angle-up'
    } %}
    {{ type_class[type] }}
{% endmacro %}
```